# throwing an instance with no reason

Tags: c++

I have a hard time to debbug this program.
The purpose of the program is to covert a string in a following way.
aaabccddd → abccddd → abddd → abd
Delete the two adjacent element, if they are the same alphabet.
Keep doing this several times, until got a result that cant do it anymore.
If the result dont have any alphabet print out Empty String.

I face a serious problem, my program throwing an instant of 'std::length_error'.
And i check my code. I cant problem in it. Can someone please tell me what happened,
and how to fix it.
This is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string data;
    cin >> data;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; i++){
        if(data[i] == data[i+1]){
            data.erase(data.begin()+i, data.begin()+i+2);
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    if(data.size() == 0){
        cout << "Empty String";
    }else{
        cout << data;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are some imformation about the program.
This is input:

```
aa
```

This is execution result:

```
aa
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_create

--------------------------------
Process exited after 94.29 seconds with return value 3
```

but sometimes the program can run successfully and
This is input:

```
aaabccddd
```

This is execution result:

```
aaabccddd
abd
--------------------------------
Process exited after 11.27 seconds with return value 0
```

I dont know what happened. Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: This seems to be a typo. `i = -1;` or a simple misunderstanding. It needs to be `i -= 1;`.

Comment: the length of your string is 2. and data.begin() + i + 2 (when i = 0) will try to refer to the 3rd element. Thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: `std::string::size` returns a `size_t` which is unsigned. I wonder what happens when `data.size()` returns 0, and I subtract 1 from it, and then compare it with an `int`? Try to see what happens when you run this: `int i=0; size_t s=0; if (i < s-1) std::cout << "Huh?" << std::endl;` Now, try to figure out when you string contains just "aa", and your first iteration of the loop gets rid of the whole thing, guess what happens on the 2nd iteration of your loop?

Comment: It will perform `i++` after `i = -1;` so the program should execute successfully i think. and i dont know why the program will throw an instance.

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop that automatically increments `i`.  Use a `while` loop and take full control whether `i` increments or not.  This would make the loop much easier, as erasing (in your example) multiple `a` characters in a row should **not** increment `i`.  For example `aaaaaaaaaab`.  How is your `for` loop going to handle that?  It can't, since `i` needs to be "stuck" on the second `a` after each erasure, and shouldn't budge until it gets to `b`

Comment: With an empty string `size()` is zero. Being an unsigned integer, sutracting 1 will yield a huge value, not -1.

Comment: No, it will not "execute successfully". The loop will execute, and try to examine the 1st and the 2nd character of the empty string, valiantly. Then the 2nd and the 3rd (string still empty), and so on, scribbling on innocent memory infinitely until the poor program crashes. Try the experiment I suggested. You'll be surprised. Then, spend a few minutes to learn how to use your debugger, in order to show what happens on each line of your program, as it runs. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: I dont think `i =-1;` is a typo. The intent seems to be to "restart" the for loop, though it isn't necessary.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- I think you're right.  But it isn't even intuitive, at least to me, if you picture how the erasure should work.  The index should remain stuck on the next character and keep erasing until it hits a different character.

Comment: Well, setting it to -1 may be necessary, if your intent is to start with "cabba", and then end up with "c". Can't assume that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is probably a case of taking "Keep doing this several times, until got a result that cant do it anymore." too literally.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- You know, if you gave this to a non-programmer, but someone who knows how to use a keyboard, they would say "well, you keep the cursor over the second "a", and you just keep hitting the delete key until you get to a different letter.".  And you know what -- they would be right.  Thus you simulate that in the program.  They wouldn't say "place the cursor at the beginning each time you erase one "a" character", which is what the OP is doing.

Comment: Fair warning: `data.size() - 1` will *not* bode well for you as a calculated value for your `i` conditional when `data` is zero-length (eg. an empty string).

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik maybe its critical reason because the program show Huh?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik yes im suprised with the experiment. it is a critical issue about my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to iterate over a container and want to erase something inside the loop, use the following pattern:

```
for (auto i = container.begin(); i != container.end();) {
  if (...some condition...) {
    // erase:
    i = container.erase(i);
  } else {
    // keep:
    ++i;
  }
}
```

The `erase()` function will return a valid iterator to the item after the range you just deleted.
You do need to use proper iterators for this to work. So in your case, your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data;
    cin >> data;
    for (auto i = data.begin(); i < data.end() - 1;) {
        if (i[0] == i[1]) {
            i = data.erase(i, i + 2);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }

    if (data.empty()) {
        cout << "Empty String\n";
    } else {
        cout << data << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```